# Change data in flipped DataGridView

Tags: c#, binding, datagridview, flip

I have an entity of a class with many properties and want to implement a GUI to edit their values. It works fine with a DataGridView, but as I only have one instance of the class and many properties the DataGridView becomes very wide and has only one row.

I tried to flip the DataGridView using this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19313/Displaying-Vertical-Rows-in-DataGrid-View

However, once flipped, the DataGridView seems to discard any changes I make to the data. How can I make it possible to edit the data in flipped mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you really should be using [PropertyGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx) since you have one instance of the class and many properties.

Answer (score 0):

I realized the DataGridView is not the correct thing to use when trying to edit properties.
Instead I found the PropertyGrid, which seems to do exactly what I was trying to accomplish, and even supports categories.

Edit: Oh, too late